# Apply Positive Lookahead only if Capturing Group was found

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to create a regex that matches strings (in C#). This is the test I'm trying to make:

```
"bla\"" => matches "bla\""
"bla\" => no matches
@"bla\" => matches @"bla\" 
@"bla\"" => matches only @"bla\"
```

That is, if the @ symbol precedes the quote, the regex ignores the control character (\).

My regex is like this so far:

```
^@?(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)+?\1$
```

My only problem is recognizing the @ and dealing with the control character...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can there be other backslashes in the string, other than the ones escaping the `'` or `"` delimiters?

Comment: All backslashes form a control pair, but the only ones that matter are the ones that matches the start quote.

Comment: It's not clear if those test cases are desired matches or your current output. Please clarify.

Comment: I hope its clearer now, if not, tell me.

Comment: `@"bla\"" => matches only @"bla\"` but your regex matches the whole.

Comment: Yeah I was describing the desired behavior. It was solved though. See answer.

Comment: and what about this one `@"bla\\""`?

Comment: @revo Works as expected https://regexr.com/4173n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^@(["']).*?\1|^(["'])(?:\\\2|(?!\\\2)(?!\2).)*\2
```

https://regex101.com/r/BvcLJB/3

The general idea is to alternate between (matching the @ and continuing until the initial delimiter is found again) and (matching the initial delimiter and continuing until a non-escaped delimiter is found again).

Breaking it down: Alternate between

- `^@(["']).*?\1` - Match `@` and initial delimiter, lazy-repeat until initial delimiter is found again

and

- `^(["'])(?:\\\2|(?!\\\2)(?!\2).)*\2`:

  - `^(["'])(?:` - Match initial delimiter, then a group of either:

    - `\\\2` - an *escaped* initial delimiter, or
    - `(?!\\\2)(?!\2).` - any character which isn't the start of an escaped initial delimiter, nor any character which is a non-escaped delimiter
  - `)*\2` Repeat the previous group until you reach the initial delimiter again

Since there has been some discussion in the comments about it, the big repeated group in the second alternation *can* be repeated lazily if one wants to (end with `)*?\2` instead of `)*\2`) , which may reduce steps needed for some strings, but it's not necessary.

Comment: It shouldnt match `""bla"`. Actually it should be able to match `""`

Comment: Ok, see edit - add in negative lookahead for the initial delimiter

Comment: Yeah that and the lazy operator I added at the end did the job! Please add it so I can mark the answer: `^@(["']).*?\1|^(["'])(?:\\\2|(?!\\\2).)*?\2`

Comment: I'm curious, what sort of string was the lazy-repeat necessary for? I would have thought that the `(?!\2)` in the group before would have been enough

Comment: Then why did you edit your answer earlier than knowing the reason?

Comment: @revo It works either way, and takes slightly fewer steps, but I'm wondering if it's necessary or just a (trivial) improvement

Comment: Then why did you ask OP? I'm exactly taking this into the consideration if you are wondering what it does why you edited at the first place.

Comment: @revo I know that it's a trivial improvement - there's nothing wrong with making it lazy, fewer steps are good even if the effect is minimal. But I don't know if it's *necessary*, which OP seemed to imply. I can't think of one, can you think of a string for which the lazy operator is necessary?

Comment: On the input strings you have run the test it may take fewer steps for engine to complete a match but it doesn't mean it will behave the same for all the untested ones. Although there may be nothing wrong with making it lazy, but your reasoning isn't acceptable. I still have questions about the main problem waiting for OP to clear things so I can't answer your question right now.

Comment: @CertainPerformance this was the case that needed the lazy modifier: `"bla"bla"`

Comment: @MatheusSimon It looks to match the initial `"bla"` regardless? https://regex101.com/r/BvcLJB/4 vs https://regex101.com/r/BvcLJB/5

Comment: @revo Well I guess it works for me, but seeing as recognition of strings is something that more people would search for, I tried to make it a little better. For example I recently changed it to: `@(["'])[\S\s]*?\1|(["'])(?:\\\2|(?!\\\2).)*?\2` so strings starting with @ can be multiline.

Comment: @MatheusSimon My last comment on your question's awaiting for your response.

Comment: @MatheusSimon I think I figured it out, it's because you didn't include the `(?!\2)` I mentioned on the fourth comment and in the answer (there are *two* negative lookaheads in the second alternation of the repeated group). So, it looks like the lazy-repeat is unnecessary.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ohh thats right... removed it now its working. Thanks.